# How to close MatInput in FlatTreeControl?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-tree-component

There is an example of FlatTreeControl with possibility to dynamically add new node
https://v15.material.angular.io/components/tree/examples#tree-checklist

I want to add Cancel button for input field but without any success.

I've tried

```
<mat-form-field #myFormField>
  <input matInput placeholder="Input">
</mat-form-field>

<button (click)="myFormField.close()">Close</button>
```

but got different errors: 
TS2339: Property 'close' does not exist on type 'MatFormField' 
TS2339: Property 'close' does not exist on type 'MatFormFieldControl '. 
TS2339: Property 'blur' does not exist on type 'MatInput'.

How to add a Cancel button for input field in this example?

Optional question: How to add a protection from opening multiply input fields?